# Is "to pend" a verb?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, word-usage

The word "pending" is quite frequently used in English. Accordingly, I used to think that "to pend" is a verb, and some of the online English dictionaries tend to agree. However, my copy of Oxford dictionary of English doesn't recognise "to pend" as a verb. Is it not? For example, is this ungrammatical: "there were still five cases pending on the decision of the Highest Court."? And later: "those five cases used to pend on the decision of the Highest Court".

Answer (score 3):

> **verb** (used without object)
>
> 1. to remain undecided or unsettled.
> 2. to hang.
> 3. Obsolete. to depend.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pend)

Comment: Any comments on why the downvote?

Comment: Just the ever-irritating driveby downvoter, a plague upon this site. Here, let me help.

Comment: Are the examples I mentioned in the original question ungrammatical? It would be great if the answer provided more insight why my dictionary doesn't have the word (Oxford Dictionary of English in the Dictionary app on Apple macOS). Is it rarely used?

Answer (score 2):

[oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pend#pend_Verb_500):

> Verb
>
> *Business*
>
> *with object* To treat as pending; to postpone deciding on or attending to; to defer.